# Do jQuery functions that affect certain elements have to exist after the elements in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running into a problem where my jQuery functions will only work correctly when they exist at the very bottom of the page before the closing body and html tags. Is this standard for functions that affect certain elements to have to come after these elements?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: Are you using the ready function?  It is a good practice to place your javascript at the bottom of the page anyways unless it is absolutely necessary to have it load before the elements on the page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, otherwise the elements are not in the DOM yet.

The common solution is executing your code via the DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

There is also a shortcut syntax for it (I wouldn't use it though as it is less clear):

```
$(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: I always use `$(function() {` over `$(document).ready(function() {`. We're coders. Aren't we known for being lazy?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the document to load before you can start to manipulate the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Or more succinctly:

```
$(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if your function depends on the styles and properties of elements being loaded, you will have to use

```
window.onload = function () { /* actions to do after page elements loaded */ };
```

This is the case, for instance, with HTML5 canvas - the canvas and the svg elements in it (along with their properties) must load first before javascript can operate on them.

In jQuery,

```
$(document).load(function() { /* actions to do after page elements loaded */ });
```

should do as well.

Of course, if your javascript simply needs the DOM to be ready (and does not depend on the properties of elements of the page to be loaded), then you could just use

```
$(function() { /* actions to do after DOM is ready */ });
```